# eloquent get 4 posts from all categories

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, eloquent-relationship

i have some categories and many posts in each category
i want to get all categories with its last 4 posts

my code with eloquent is :

```
$allcats = Category::whereHas('posts')->with(['posts' => function($q){
            $q->take(4);
}])->get();
```

but the problem is : this query will take just and just 4 post (4 post from all of the categories)

can do this with eloquent?
or can id do this with query builder??